# link to another action

Tags: php, .htaccess, zend-framework, hyperlink, zend-framework-routing

i am unsing zend framework. i have a view linked to a controller, home,

so:

```
application>controllers>HomeController.php

application>views>scripts>home>index.phtml
```

in the index.phtml page i have a link to an action in the same controller:

```
application>views>scripts>home>add.phtml
```

the code for the link is:

```
<a href="../application/controllers/home/add">add</a>
```

Not only does this not work but i am sure its not the best way to do this in zend framework.

please note i am using wamp

```
http://localhost/sites/url/public/home/add
```

when using:

```
<?php
    echo '<a href="' . $this->url(array('controller' => 'home', 'action' => 'add')) . '">Add Job</a>';  
?>
```

I get this error message:

```
Message: Invalid controller specified (sites)
```

this is whats in my htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Could you give the url of your homepage (i.e., what is in your browser's location bar) and url given by `$this->url()` (i.e., what's in this a href="")?

Comment: I mean you probably have to add this line - `resources.frontController.baseUrl = "/sites/url/public"` to your `config.ini` file; still I wonder is it the right path.

Comment: i havent set up a.htacces file and i acces my site by clicking on my folder, clicking public, then clicking index file

Comment: But you still do open your website in your web-browser, right? What's in its upper bar then? And what's in that link (press `Ctrl-U` to view the source).

Comment: The htacces you posted is the stock implementation the ZF sets up so it will work for most situations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the url helper for this:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('controller' => 'index', 
                                     'action' => 'index', 
                                     'module' => 'module1')); ?>" title="test">
```

**UPDATE**

This is how your `.htaccess` should like:

```
SetEnv ENVIRONMENT development

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|swf|txt)$
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: In which directory is your index.php within the .htaccess?

Comment: @RyanMurphy And where's your index.php? You should have the .htaccess too. Man the thing is you need both index.php and .htaccess on this folder: /sites/url/public/

Comment: i have the index.php in the public folder not a htaccess

Comment: @RyanMurphy Is there `RewriteBase` line? What's in it?

Comment: @RyanMurphy If you access this link http://localhost/sites/url/public/home/add removing the `$this->url()` part it works? If so, your `.htaccess` is working

Comment: just redirects to a homepage of a different site in my sites folder

Comment: @RyanMurphy Are you sure there isn't any index.php/.htacess before the your app public folder? You should at least be abble to access http://localhost/sites/url/public/index.php Are you able to do so?

Comment: yes i am. but when i add a link to another page and click on that link the situation described in the question happens

Comment: @RyanMurphy If you're able to access both http://localhost/sites/url/public/index.php and http://localhost/sites/url/public/ it's working. If the .htaccess is properly set then you should be able to acess http://localhost/sites/url/public/home/add Are you sure this last link is not working? You need to fix this step first before going to the url part on the view

Answer (score 2):

when using relative and absolute links in ZF, it works pretty much the same as outside of ZF
except that all request route through index.php so you are not actually routing to the directory, your just telling the router where the link goes:

```
<a href="/home/add">add</a>
```

or

```
<a href="http://mysite.com/home/add">add</a>
```

The url helper would be the preferred way to do this and should have worked. In your case I suspect the localhost pathing os creating difficulties with your urls, I know it always did with mine.

Setting up a vhost for each project will make this issue disappear. If you need help with a vhost setup there a number of good resources here on SO.

http://blog.srmklive.com/2010/12/27/how-to-create-virtual-hosts-using-zend-server-ce/

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to refer to the `application` folder in your links, because that folder can be located outside your `htdocs`/`www`/`public_html` folder.

The link should look like: `http://yourdomain.com/home/add` or `http://localhost/home/add`, depending where you installed your application.

The best way to do it in my opinion, is either use the `$this->baseUrl()` method (works only in views, not controllers), or you can define a constant in bootstrap.php, which holds your baseUrl.

Comment: You're doing it wrong ;) this is a job for the url helper. Baseurl is usually used when requiring js or css files.

Comment: @EduardLuca Meehhh... Just because you can doesn't mean you should: http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/files/2011/03/SOLID_6EC97F9C.jpg

Comment: @RyanMurphy wamp doesn't has nothing with it.